# MYSQL - triple Inner Join and SUM

Tags: mysql, sum, inner-join

**Here my tables:**
invites

```
id | inviteFromID | inviteToID | timestamp | joined
---------------------------------------------------
1  | 1            | 234567890  | 2013-02-02| 1
2  | 1            | 345678901  | 2013-02-02| 1
```

player:

```
id | FacebookID | first_name | last_name
---------------------------------------------------
1  | 123456789  | Dude       | Master
2  | 234567890  | Super      | Man
3  | 345678901  | Bat        | Man
```

Rounds:

```
id | PlayerID | round | played | status
---------------------------------------------------
1  | 1        | 1      | 1     | 1
2  | 1        | 2      | 1     | 0
3  | 2        | 1      | 1     | 1
```

**In this case:**
Player with the ID = 1 would have 1 own Point and ID = 2 would have 1 own Point.
But ID 1 invited 2 so ID = 1 in total has two points (explanation below) .

**Relationships:**
- player.id = invites.inviteFromID
- player.id = rounds.playerID

**Description:**
A user from the table "player" can invite ppl to a game. The games are played in rounds.
When a User played a game, the "rounds" table updated with "played = 1" and the userId and "status = 1(if won) or status = 0 (if not won)".

To get the points for each User isn't the problem.

**Problem:**
..the problem is, that every invited user gives the inviter his points too.

So if user A (won 2 rounds = 2 points) invited B, and B played 3 rounds and won 3 rounds ( = 3 points), the overall points of user A are 5 ( Points from A + Points from B).
And that is true for all users A invited to the game, so if user A invited B, C, and D, he will get their points too.

And here I stuck. I tried to **Inner Join** player, invites and rounds but It didn't work and I 'm stuck right now.

**Best Output would be**

```
PlayerID | ownPoints | otherPoints | totalPoints
---------------------------------------------------
1        | 1         | 1           | 2
2        | 1         | 0           | 1
```

Can someone help me please? :)

EDIT:
**Function - getPointsFromPlayer (DEPRECATED: "points" isn't available anymore)**

```
SELECT 
    p.points AS OwnPoints, count(p.id) AS UsersCount, SUM(pi.points) AS SumPoints 
FROM 
    player AS p 
INNER JOIN invites AS i ON p.id = i.inviteFromID 
INNER JOIN player AS pi ON i.inviteToId  = pi.facebookID
WHERE 
    p.id = :inviter AND i.joined = 1 
GROUP BY 
    p.id
```

Comment: Let me edit it, sorry!

Comment: need of your query that updates the db

Comment: Didn't have that yet. I'm coding the backend functionality right now.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it, it was simpler as I thought:

```
        SELECT 
            SUM(CASE WHEN r.status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS won_rounds
            FROM invites i
            INNER JOIN rounds r ON  i.inviteToID = r.facebookID
            WHERE r.played = 1 AND i.joined = 1 AND i.inviteFromID = :facebookID
```

Nevertheless, thank you all!